Can't redirect error 500 to custom error page in ASP.NET MVC 5
I have been trying to learn how to create a custom error page for my ASP.NET MVC application. I have created a new controller with an action and a new view for this.
public ActionResult Error(int id, string message, string stackTrace)
{
    Response.StatusCode = id;
    ViewBag.Message = message;
    ViewBag.StackTrace = stackTrace;

    return View("~/Views/PaginaErro/PaginaErro.cshtml");
}

And this is the Application_Error method that I have added to the Global.asax.cs:
protected void Application_Error()
{
    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();

    var httpException = exception as HttpException;

    int httpCode = httpException?.GetHttpCode() ?? (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

    Server.ClearError();

    Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPage/Error?id=" + httpCode + "&message=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(exception.Message) + "&stackTrace=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(exception.StackTrace));
}

Web.config:
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPage/Error">
    <error redirect="~/ErrorPage/Error/404" statusCode="404"/>
    <error redirect="~/ErrorPage/Error/500" statusCode="500"/>
</customErrors>

Now, when I receive an error 404, it works perfectly. I hits first the Application_Error method and then after that it goes to the Error action method in the ErrorPageController.
But the issue that I encounter is with the error 500. I can't find what is causing that. Once it reaches the Response.Redirect, it never goes to my ErrorPageController, it keeps looping in the Application_Error.
The exception.Message of my http 500 error is:

The view 'Error' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:\r\n~/Areas/Erp/Views/AjusteDeEstoque/Error.aspx\r\n~/Areas/Erp/Views/AjusteDeEstoque/Error.ascx\r\n~/Areas/Erp/Views/Shar...

I don't have a view called Error, so I don't know why is it searching for that one.
I'm not sure if this helps, but here is my RouteConfig:
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}


First off, you should note that the info in web.config in your case is redundant - your Application_Error() function catches any exception and redirects it to the /ErrorPage/Error route.
I recreated your case and was having issues even entering Application_Error() with the web.config settings - I would encourage you to remove that section and then try again, unless you are adamant on keeping the web.config settings in which case you should change your approach.
Finally, your redirect will essencially be transmitting the error message and stack trace in the URL, which can potentially be too much information - you should rethink this way of passing information.

You are right. I removed the custom error tag in my web.config, and with that i was able to get the same error as I would get in a normal error screen. But it still does not reach my controller. I added a Debug.WriteLine and it loops this error now:
A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (stackTrace="...voker.<>c.<BeginInvokeSynchron...").

I would guess the query string value is being interpreted as an issue, maybe because it looks like code and could be malicious...? The query string mentioned here is regarding your stackTrace parameter - you should really choose to share this to your controller in another way

Thank you for the tip, i will try with a different method. But for now, I was able to circumvent that error by adding the [ValidateInput(false)] attribute in my Error action. Now, I'm finally able to hit my Action, but once it reaches the return View, it never opens the view.

"Never opens the view" is a bit of a broad statement - is there an error? Is the page blank? I can't recreate your error on my end.
Personally, I would recommend you pause here and consider fixing up this part instead of circumventing the error, as it might come back to bite you.

Sorry for my past statement, it was very vague. I found the issue, since i'm generating the 500 error through a bad Ajax call, the HTML of my error page is being returned as a response from the server, and making it not open it. I will try a few more things here and see what I manage. Thank you for the help, your clarification about the web.config helped a lot!
